# VBA Excel Err.Number 75 / Dropbox

Tags: excel, vba

I introduced Dropbox as a method to automatically backup "working" Excel files. These Excel files open and read .txt files that are generated by a VB6 app.
The system worked without problem until a point in time when file access was denied.

I then moved all working Excel files to a non-Dropbox area of my drive.
Again this has worked well until today - when the same problem has returned.

I have checked file permissions at every level and do not see an explanation.

Does anyone have experience of this and a solution?